# Interstitial Sites in unit cell

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry

I wanted to calculate how many interstitial sites (tetrahedral and octahedral) are present in a simple unit cell and their location and radius.
I am guessing they are at the center of unit cell and at the center of each edge.
But can someone please confirm it and explain this in detail? Thanks

Comment: Since a 'unit cell' is not a uniquely defined thing, you should be careful. For example, a Wigner-Seitz unit cell will have a lattice atom at the center, which means that can't be an interstitial site as well.